Funnel Report GA4 Filter on pagePath Using Google Analytics API
I am working with the Google Analytics API to generate a funnel report, but I am running into an issue when trying to filter on pagePath. I believe I am setting up my filters correctly, the report does not seem to apply the pagePath filter as expected.
Here is the code I am using:
export const getPageFunnel = async (
  start: Date,
  end: Date,
  startPath: string,
  endPaths: string[],
  propertyId: string = pId
) => {

  try {
    const [response] = await v1alphaAnal.runFunnelReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [
        {
          startDate: start.toISOString().split('T')[0],
          endDate: end.toISOString().split('T')[0],
        },
      ],
     
      funnel: {
        steps: [
          {
            name: 'Start Path',
            filterExpression: {
              funnelFieldFilter: {
                fieldName: 'pagePath',
                stringFilter: {
                  matchType: 'EXACT',
                  value: startPath,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          {
            name: 'End Paths',
            filterExpression: {
              andGroup: {
                expressions: endPaths.map((path) => ({
                  funnelFieldFilter: {
                    fieldName: 'pagePath',
                    stringFilter: {
                      matchType: 'EXACT',
                      value: path,
                    },
                  },
                })),
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });
    console.log('Funnel Report:', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    type d = typeof response;
    type simple = SimplifyDeep<RequiredDeep<d>>;
    return response;
  } catch (error) {}
};

Problem Description
Despite setting the fieldName to pagePath in the filterExpression for both the start and end steps of the funnel, the filter does not seem to work as expected. The response does not reflect the filtered pagePath values, and I am unable to figure out why.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Verified that pagePath values are correct and exist in the dataset.
Checked for any typos or syntax errors.
Ensured that the date ranges are correct and align with the available data.
Logged the response to see if any errors or warnings are provided, but the response looks normal.
Question
How can I correctly filter on pagePath in the funnel report using the Google Analytics API? Is there something I am missing in the setup of the filter expressions?
